# My tests fails on jenkins but pass in local. Using Jmockit @Injectable field injection on @Tested instance for the class under test

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jenkins, jmockit

I have the child class under test `BoyTest.java`.  BoyTest extends a test class called `GirlTest`. I have injected a list using `@Injectable(Jmockit)` in `GirlTest`.

Now when I try to inject the list from GirlTest on `@Tested` instance of BoyTest. I see my test fail since the list is not injected. Test fail since, expected is empty list and actual is list containing a JSON.
`Jmockit` version under use is : v1.41 and JDK version 1.8.0_181

```
public class GirlTest {
    @Tested
    private Girl girl;

    @Injectable
    private List<someType> list;
}

public class BoyTest extends GirlTest {
    @Tested
    private Boy boy;


    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        lis.add(json)
        assertThat(boy.getJsons()).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(json));
    }
}
```

> Test result: Expecting List element get added to list before assertion
>   statement is run and expecting test to pass Actual , test pass in
>   local,  expecting test pass on Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

maybe you has'nt configure maven-surefire-plugin
you can try to add these codes as follows in your pom.xml file

```html
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.3</version>
   <configuration>
      <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/mockit/jmockit/0.998/jmockit-0.998.jar</argLine>
      <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

make sure that this line is configured.

```html
<argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/mockit/jmockit/0.998/jmockit-0.998.jar</argLine>
```

then you can use jmockit on jenkins